# Why does the setxkbmap compose key mess with other keys?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xkb

I just found a tip to set the compose key manually:

```
setxkbmap -option compose:caps
```

Unfortunately, after running this several keypresses act as if the compose key had been pressed. For example, to get a tilde, I now have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>~</kbd> *twice*, and I can no longer figure out how to get a single or double quote - When I press that key twice (*without* pressing Caps Lock) I get a single `´` (without <kbd>Shift</kbd>) or `¨` (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>) character.

```
$ setxkbmap -print 
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(dvorak-intl)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(caps)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Setting the compose key to the more popular <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> did not help - The results are the same with the following settings:

```
$ setxkbmap -print 
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(dvorak-intl)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(ralt)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Stranger still, even after disabling the compose key with `setxkbmap -option` the keys are still messed up.

On a different machine with GNOME 3 and similar settings it works just fine (<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> produces `å`, while a single press of <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>~</kbd> produces `~`):

```
$ setxkbmap -print 
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(dvorak-alt-intl)+ch:2+inet(evdev)+compose(caps)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Maybe it's an LXDE issue - I'll test it next week.

Comment: I don't get that with compose set to ralt, but I didn't set it the same way.

Comment: @Rob: Changing it to `ralt` did not work.

Comment: That behavior sounds like us-intl. Try pressing space after the troublesome keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was actually the keyboard layout - **Switching to English (Dvorak alternative international no dead keys) (`XKBVARIANT="dvorak-alt-intl"` in `/etc/default/keyboard`) fixed it.**

Unfortunately I can't find a way to [set this for my user only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36316/how-to-set-global-user-keyboard-settings-on-lxde).