# How to set separate global/user keyboard settings in LXDE?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, lxde

I need to have `English (US)` and no compose key for the *system*, and I'd like `English (Dvorak alternative international no dead keys)` + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as the compose key for *myself*. How can I set this up?

I tried setting `dvorak-alt-intl` in `lxkeymap`, but it only worked until I logged in again. I also tried to set `@setxkbmap -option compose:caps` in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`, but that didn't work after logging in again.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try adding a setxkbmap command such as this -

```
@setxkbmap -option "compose:menu"
```

to

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

and restart your session.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it worked but it looks like that was a mistake. Maybe Ubuntu+LXDE is not really the same as Lubuntu (rephrasing question).